# Migrate ModelData from Ext GWT 2 to 3

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have this legacy Ext GWT 2 code that I need to migrate with Ext GWT 3:

```
    for (ModelData data: store.getRootItems()) {

        Element voiceElement = DOM.createDiv();
        Element labelElement;
        Element optionsElement;

        String text = data.get("text");
        String url = data.get("url");
                    ...
           }
```

How do I convert this code to Ext GWT 3 when ModelData is part of Ext GWT 3.0.

Comment: Did you watch this video ? http://www.sencha.com/conference/session/migrating-from-ext-gwt-2.x-to-3.0